# Create MailChimp campaign

Tags: vb.net, mailchimp

```
   Dim CCoptions As campaignCreateOptions = New campaignCreateOptions()
    CCoptions.from_email = "chimpmail12@gmail.com"
    CCoptions.from_name = "dummy"
    CCoptions.to_email = "vettr@gmail.com"
    CCoptions.subject = "HelloWorld"
    CCoptions.list_id = "0fd2345g"
    CCoptions.title = "who am i?"

    Dim CCcontent As Dictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    CCcontent.Add("html", "some pretty html content  message")
    CCcontent.Add("text", "hdfjhfk000")

    Dim params As campaignCreateParms = New campaignCreateParms
    params.content = CCcontent
    params.options = CCoptions
    params.type = EnumValues.campaign_type.auto
    params.apikey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-us2"

    Dim CCinput As campaignCreateInput = New campaignCreateInput(params)

    Dim CCcmd As campaignCreate = New campaignCreate(CCinput)
    Dim CCoutput As campaignCreateOutput = CCcmd.Execute()

    Label1.Text = CCoutput.result
```

I am not getting any answer, can you pls point out my problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not getting any answers from people, you might want to see if any e-mails are being sent and if they are being sent at the right times to the right people.

Comment: Hi thanks for your quick reply, i am using PerceptiveMCAPI. i should get campaign id in the label box. but its not returning anything. thats my problem

Comment: thanks, for your help i figure it out. i changed  params.type = EnumValues.campaign_type.auto

Comment: thanks, for your help i figure it out. i changed params.type = EnumValues.campaign_type.auto to params.type = EnumValues.campaign_type.regular